# Wrong output of .ini file after parsing

Tags: php, parsing, output, ini

I try to get values with php of an ini file which looks like this:

```
[hash] 
key = yFrTYcqH116ZL|XOJnMCLrLUf@RfqrNB
iv = 35jL|HRNSDhn38T39MK9wdN26CkcYRKT
```

The ini file is created with a python script, which chooses random chars of a string.

The string looks like this:
`string = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789=@#|'`

Finally I try to parse the ini file and get it's values:

```
$key_ini = parse_ini_file("..\key.ini");
$key = $key_ini['key'];
$iv = $key_ini['iv'];

echo $key;
echo '<br>';
echo $iv;
```

The output is pretty weird:

```
0
35
```

May is it possible that I have used an invalid character in the string or is the format of the ini file wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you change the ini file ?

Comment: @frz3993 its generated by python code. But yes, I could

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an `.ini` file, use double quotes `""` to indicate string, so it will be parsed without modification. To solve your problem you can either double quote the values in your `.ini` file, example:

```
[hash] 
key = "yFrTYcqH116ZL|XOJnMCLrLUf@RfqrNB"
iv = "35jL|HRNSDhn38T39MK9wdN26CkcYRKT"
```

OR, you can tell `parse_ini_file()` to use the `INI_SCANNER_RAW` mode, example:

```
$key_ini = parse_ini_file("..\key.ini", false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

Although, for some reasons I personally prefer the double quotes.

Comment: Thank you this worked very well.
Btw I had to modify the string. I had to remove the "